# Using Google Retail API to build category pages

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to build hierarchical category pages similar to the ones we see in common e-commerce web sites, the user will press on Dresses, or Pants, under Clothing for example.

I've added the Categories values in the product catalog similar to:

Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses

Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses > Maxi

Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses > Midi

however, when I use the below query in the search API, I get the same results regardless of what the pageCatogories value is.

```
POST https://retail.googleapis.com/v2/projects/******/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/servingCo...] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
"pageCategories": [
"Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Dresses"
],
"visitorId": "1",
"query": ""
}
```

I do not have user events logged yet as I didn't launch the app so far. If this method depends on active user events, how can I build hierarchical category pages before the launch using Google's Retail API?